# Time complexity of the fast exponentiation method

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotics, recurrence-relation

I am trying to analyse the time complexity of the fast exponentiation method,
which is given as

$$x^n=
\begin{cases}
 x^\frac{n}{2}.x^\frac{n}{2}       &\text{if n is even}\newline
x.x^{n-1}   &\text{if n is odd} \newline
1 &\text{if n=0}
\end{cases}
$$

I tried to write it as,
$$
T(n)=\begin{cases}
T(\frac{n}{2}).T(\frac{n}{2}) &\text{if n is even}\newline
T(n-1) &\text{if n is odd}\newline
1 &\text{if n=0}
\end{cases}
$$

I think I am lacking somewhere and so not able write correct recurrence relation here.

Need help to do so.

Comment: 1. Try editing your question to write down your justification for this equation.  Why do you think each case is correct?  Where did you get that from?  I suspect a bit of "[rubber duck debugging](https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/)" might help you spot a problem in your proposed solution.  2. Then, take a look at http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/23593/755.  This topic also tends to be covered in any decent algorithms textbook.  I suggest you study that material, then see if you can get any further, and edit your question with where you're stuck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of time complexity, it is much simpler here to count multiplications; I'll leave you to figure out the relation between multiplications and time complexity (the exact relation depends on the computation model).

Denote the number of multiplications when computing $x^n$ using your algorithm by $S(n)$.
Let's consider your cases from bottom to top:

- Calculating $x^n$ for $n = 0$. The answer is $1$, so no multiplications are needed: $S(1) = 0$.
- Calculating $x^n$ for $n$ odd. In this case we first calculate $x^{n-1}$ using the same method, which takes $S(n-1)$ multiplications by definition. Then we multiply the result by $x$, which uses up one multiplication. This gives $S(n) = S(n-1) + 1$ in this case.
- Calculating $x^n$ for $n>0$ even. In this case we first calculate $x^{n/2}$ using the same method, which takes $S(n/2)$ multiplications by definition. Then we multiply the result by itself, which uses up one multiplication. This gives $S(n) = S(n/2) + 1$ in this case.

In total, we get the following recurrence for the number of multiplications:
$$
S(n) = \begin{cases}
0 & n = 0 \\
S(n-1) + 1 & n \text{ odd} \\
S(n/2) + 1 & n>0 \text{ even}
\end{cases}
$$
We can improve on the algorithm slightly using the identity $x^1 = x$. This gives the following alternate recurrence:
$$
S'(n) = \begin{cases}
0 & n \leq 1 \\
S'(n-1) + 1 & n>1 \text{ odd} \\
S'(n/2) + 1 & n>0 \text{ even}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Ok ! when we have a two case relation like                                            $$T(n) = \begin{cases}
0 & n = 0 \\
T(n-1) + 1 &  \text{ otherwise} 
\end{cases}$$ then it become easier to compute Big-O by expanding  .How do I compute big-O by expansion for the relation you told me.....

Comment: You'll have to be creative.

Answer (score 0):

You somehow confuse the result of the multiplications and the time they take.

$$x^{n/2}\cdot x^{n/2}$$

does not take $T(\frac n2)\cdot T(\frac n2)$ units of time but $T(\frac n2)+M+T(\frac n2)$ where $M$ denotes the time for a multiplication (assuming they can be done in constant time).

Hence the complete recurrence

$$T(n)=\begin{cases}2T(\frac n2)+M\\T(n-1)+M\\T(1)\end{cases}.$$

We can solve it for the best and worst cases.

**Best:**

$\frac n2$ decreases $n$ faster than $n-1$. So the best case is achieved when $n$ is a power of $2$, let $2^m$. After $m$ applications of the first line, we have

$$T(2^m)=2^mT(1)+(2^{m-1}+2^{m-2}+\cdots 1)M=2^mT(1)+(2^m-1)M.$$

**Worst:**

Occurs when every division leads to an odd number, which is when $n$ is a power of $2$ minus $1$. We easily see that every reduction by one bit takes $2M$ multiplications instead of $1$, leading to a similar formula.